# Filter in Django Admin via a ManyToMany field with Through

Tags: python, django, django-models

My `models.py`:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Person(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

class PersonRole(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Project(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    person = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through=PersonRole)
```

Now, in my admin back-end I'd like to add a nice filtering with `list_filter`. This filter should make it possible to filter by the schools that a person is attached to a project. In other words, if John (belonging to school 'no. 1') is attached to project no. 3, I'd like the projects table on the backend to show only project no. 3.
I suppose I should customise a [simplelistfilter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/admin/filters/#using-a-simplelistfilter). First of all, though, I'm a bit stuck as to how to get the list of schools attached to the persons attached to a project.

My attempt so far is:

```
class PersonRole(models.Model):

    [...]

    def get_school(self):
        return self.person.school


class Project(models.Model):

    @admin.display(description='PI School')
    def get_PI_school(self):
        return [p for p in self.person.get_school()]
```

`admin.py`:

```
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("get_PI_school",) #This is just to see if the field is populated
```

With this, I get `'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'get_school'`.

Answer (score 1):

You use `.get_school()` on the `PersonRole` object:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    @admin.display(description='PI School')
    def get_PI_school(self):
        return [p.get_school() for p in self.personrole_set.all()]
```

We can boost efficiency by fetching the related `Person` and `School` in the same query:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    @admin.display(description='PI School')
    def get_PI_school(self):
        return [
            p.get_school()
            for p in self.personrole_set.select_related('person__school')
        ]
```

and you can filter to a PI role with:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    @admin.display(description='PI School')
    def get_PI_school(self):
        return [
            p.get_school()
            for p in self.personrole_set.filter(
                title__contains="Principal investigator"
            )
        ]
```

given of course your `PersonRole` model still has the `title` field.

Comment: Thank you. I now get `'PersonRole' object has no attribute 'get_PI_school'`. Also, The `title` field is not relevant here: wht I want is `subject` and `school` (now added to my question, just for clarity) of the person with role "Principal Investigator". Finally, I want all this to be used in `list_filter`, which only accepts fields and classes. I'm looking into custom filter forms.

Comment: but what `ModelAdmin` do you use? For the `Project`, or the `ProjectRole`? Note that we use `p.get_school()`, not `p.get_PI_school()`.

Comment: I added the `_PI` to my own code, I left everything as is. I use it on `Project`, since I am filtering the projects. I want to filter the projects related to a person with role="Principal investigator". Moreover, I want to additional filters: projects linked to the `school` and `subject` of that person. I hope that's clearer.

Comment: @HBMCS: but in the list coprehension, you use `p.get_school()`, the method in the `Project` is `get_PI_school`, and for the `ProjectRole` (so in the list comprehension), it is `p.get_school()`.

Comment: Oft, you're right! And it was in the error message itself. Doh. OK, now I get the correct info output in a column of the table (`list_display`). I now want it in the `list_filter`. Shall I define a `class` in the `admin.py`?

Comment: @HBMCS: I think it might be better to ask a separate question, so that the questions are *reusable* to others, and that the question contains enough elements (and not too many) :).

Comment: Actually the very first lines of my question read `Now, in my admin back-end I'd like to add a nice filtering with list_filter.` :) .